# Implicit type casting in C

Tags: c, casting

please don't burn me if I'm asking a stupid question but I have problems with implicit type casting in complex statements and I want to learn it.

My code segment is;

```
int a[]={156, 490, 647};
int b[]={218, 789, 461, 750};
int x=2, y=3;
float result;

result =  (float) ( a[x] - b[y]) * 0,05 + 50;

printf ("%.2f", result);
```

What I meant here was "" (647-750) * 0,05 + 50 ""

So the requested output was:

```
44,85
```

What I got is:

```
-0,00
```

Sorry if I have done a stupid typo, I think I have made the mistake at placing the (float) but I don't know where to put it. I tried many things but couldn't solve it. Thanks..

Comment: There's no such thing as "implicit typecasting". And this doesn't have anything to do with typecasting either.

Comment: The moral: **turn on compiler warnings and fix them.**

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a typo. Seriously. A typo. It won't help anyone else, and it's got nothing to do with typecasting.

Comment: well I didn't know it has to be a dot instead of comma, so I don't think it is a typo actually

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Change `0,05` to `0.05`.

I think you come from a part of the world where `,` is used as a decimal separator. But C code always uses `.` as the decimal separator, irrespective of the compilation locale.

The `,` in your code is the [comma operator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma_operator).

> In the C and C++ programming languages, the comma operator (represented by the token ,) is a binary operator that evaluates its first operand and discards the result, and then evaluates the second operand and returns this value (and type).

So, your expression is evaluated like this:

```
result = (float) ( a[x] - b[y]) * 0;
```

And then `05 + 50` is evaluated and thrown away. Or the compiler probably just doesn't bother with it at all and just optimises it away completely.

You can write your assignment statement like this, with no casting:

```
result =  (a[x] - b[y])*0.05 + 50;
```

When you make this change, the output is as you expect.

Comment: Wouldn't the comma operator result in `(... * 0), (05 + 50)` = `55`?

Comment: @delnan If you **change** the comma to a dot? Naw.

Comment: @H2CO3 No, I'm talking about the version with the comma (edited for clarity). I'm questioning whether the comma operator explains OP's output, and by extension whether that's the actual error rather than a typo introduced in writing this question.

Comment: @delnan The code in the question does indeed produce the output as claimed. Because the comma operator has lower precedence than assignment. And if you make the change, then it produces the desired output.

Comment: After changing `0,05` to `0.05`, you can omit the type-casting. That's because multiplication of int and float returns a float anyways, and adding a float to an int returns a float, too.

Comment: Yeah, I just tried it out myself. What I didn't understand is *how* it results in -0, as the comma operator should. I forgot that `=` binds more tightly than `,` so it's actually `(result = ... * 0), (05+55)`. Move along, nothing to see here.

Comment: @delnan Yes, the comma operator explains the output, and it surely is the actual error. Also, comma has a lower precedence than the assignment operator (don't confuse it with the initializer separator.)

Comment: @delnan:- I dont understand how the output is 55. Please correct me if I am wrong but it goes like this:- 647-750 = 103 when multiplied by 0.05 gives -5.15 and then add 50 which gives 44.85.

Comment: @RahulTripathi Sssshhhh! That's not what we are talking about. You missed the point.

Comment: @RahulTripathi Read the answer. There is no multiplication with 0.05, there is a multiplication with 0 and the rest of the line (`05 + 50;`) is interpreted as second operand of the comma and hence thrown away.

Comment: @H2CO3:- I think I missed something but I did the calculation after removing the comma operator and there I guesss I missed. Is that what you guys are discussing?

Comment: @RahulTripathi I suppose it is.

Comment: @H2CO3:- Hmmm I got it late for the party ;)

Comment: Yes, if you put parentheses around the entire expression, and left the errant comma operator in instead of a decimal point, then you could get 55. Also, 05 is octal, which makes no difference, but this all gives me some evil ideas for obfuscated code. `}->`

Answer (score 2):

Use `dot .` as decimal seperator instead of `comma ,`. Try this:

```
int a[]={156, 490, 647};
int b[]={218, 789, 461, 750};
int x=2, y=3;
float result;

result =  (float) ( a[x] - b[y]) * 0.05 + 50;

printf ("%.2f", result);
```